# Как можно поместить url адреса из строки в массив?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Имеется примерно такой текст:

```
1.http://example.com(example) (пробела перед http нет намеренно)
2. https://vk.com (vk)
3. И так далее
```

Я хочу средствами `php` получить массив, который содержит только url адреса, без стороннего текста. 
Подскажите, какими методами это будет удобнее и правильнее всего сделать, хочу понять сам принцип.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы вытащить все URL адреса из текста, нужно использовать регулярные выражения. Для новичка это будет не совсем легко, ну а что делать? :)

```
<?php

$string = "1.http://example.com(example) (пробела перед http нет намеренно)
2. https://vk.com (vk)
3. И так далее";

$regExp = "/(?:http)?[s]?\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(?:\/\S*)?/";

preg_match_all($regExp, $string, $values);

var_dump($values);
```

Результат:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "http://example.com"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "https://vk.com"
  }
}
```

Может регулярное выражение на каких-то случаях может давать неверный результат, но во многих случаях работает, более продвинутые регулярные выражения с РФ доменами и т.д. можно найти в интернете под требуемую задачу :)

Comment: Но как я понимаю тут мы получим только домены? А что если адрес выглядит так: `vk.com/id1` или `example.com/index?id=1,2,3&v=7`?

Comment: @Nik Данным выражением вы получите не только домены, а полностью URL

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = '%http[^>]*.com%im';
preg_match_all($pattern, $content_post, $out);
```

В массиве `$out` будет вся выборка доменов. Но это при условии, что все домены в зоне `*.com`. Если другие зоны, то надо менять конструкцию регулярного выражения.